# Member function is not seen by Visual Studio

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012

I have a class named person. In person.h I have this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#pragma once

class person
{
private:
   std::string firstName;
   std::string lastName;
   int age;
   Resource *resource;

public:
   person(std::string first,
          std::string last,
          int age);
   ~person();
   person(person& p);

   bool operator < (const person& currentPerson) const;
   bool operator < (int number) const;

   void        setFirst(std::string first) {firstName = first;}
   void        setLast(std::string last) {lastName = last;}
   std::string getName() const;
   std::string getFirst() const;
   std::string getLast() const;
   int         getAge() const {return age;}
   void        setAge(int newAge) {age = newAge;}
   void        addResource();

   friend bool operator < (int number, const person& currentPerson);
};

bool operator < (int number, const person& currentPerson);
```

Every function works perfectly except `setFirst` and `setLast` which I just added to the class. When I call it,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include "person.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   person Kenneth("Kenneth", "Cochran", 19);
   Kenneth.addResource();
   Kenneth.setFirst("Kenny");
   Kenneth.setLast("Cochran");
   Kenneth.addResource();
   return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio says

```
freestore.cpp(14): error C2039: 'setFirst' : is not a member of 'person'
person.h(5) : see declaration of 'person'
freestore.cpp(15): error C2039: 'setLast' : is not a member of 'person'
person.h(5) : see declaration of 'person'
```

Comment: There is no flaw in the code you have chosen to show.  Consider showing the entire header.

Comment: Judging by the looks [of this sample](http://ideone.com/7LD3EK), the error is in the code you conveniently omitted (and you would likely *not* be shocked at all how frequently that happens here). After adding the members to the header, then switching to the `main()` source file and adding the calls, did you bother **saving** the header file along with the current source file before attempting to compile/link?

Comment: Yes I added it then waited a minute for the red underlines to go away, when they didn't I thought it might just not be looking and it would fix it if I tried to compile it. It didn't so I closed and reopened Visual Studio, and it still said I don't have the functions.

Comment: Edit the header file again, throw a temporary `#error Compiled this header.` inside the *bottom* include-guard of the header, save, and rebuild your project. I doesn't sound like your updated header is being included. I bring that up because the error message indicates that class `person` is found on line #5 of your header, but the header you posted has it on line #4.

Comment: Person was defined on line 5. There was a blank line after `#pragma once` that must have got lost when I was indenting the code block to post. I'll adjust it Also, the compiler does give `Compiled this header` error after the change

Comment: Next thing I'd try is closing the solution and getting rid of all VS temporary files (*.sdf, *.suo, *.user, debug/release directories), then reopening and rebuilding.

Comment: Is it possible you have two copies of person.h by accident, and freestore.cpp is including the wrong (older) one?

Comment: @JoelRondeau This worked. When I reopened the solution it did not contain the functions anymore; but after I re-added them, it worked normally. Any idea why it would do this?

Comment: If it did not contain the functions anymore, then I think there was a second copy of person.h sitting around somewhere. I don't have a good idea why it would do this. I just know it is what I do when VS is misbehaving and I can't find a good reason for it.

Comment: Well thank you. I will keep that in mind for the future.